# How to search if whole word exists in a String in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column `field` that has values like Samsung Phone.

My question is how can I get this row if I search for a string "Samsung" or "phone". I do not want any result if I give just "Sam" or "ph" as a search term.

I had tried with ILIKE operator but if I use:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where title ILIKE 'Samsung';
```

It does not give any results as it considers title should be exactly equal. Also if I use `title ILIKE '%Samsung%'` then it will work for any partial strings.

In short, I want if the input search term exists as a whole word in my  column then only give the search result.

Also, if I have multiple search term values, then any word match should be the result

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "word"?

Comment: word here is in the context that the search term should exist as it is as given in the input, in DB

Comment: Hi, did any solution work for you?

Answer (score 14):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
where title ~* '(\mphone\M)|(\msamsung\M)'
```

The above only returns values where `phone` or `samsung` are complete words. The regex modifiers`\m` and `\M` make the pattern only match for whole words.

The regex operator `~*` makes this case-insensitive. The above expression would return `Samsung Phone` or `Google Phone` but not `Sam's House`.

If you want to add more words, just add them using the "or" operator `|`

```
where title ~* '(\mphone\M)|(\msamsung\M)|(\mbhat\M)'
```

---

Note that this kind of search is not going t1o be super-fast. Regular expressions are expensive they cannot make use of any index.

Comment: I appreciate the detail provided in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use this:

```
title ~* '(^|[^\w])samsung([^\w]|$)'
```

The advantage of the above one is, it can be easily extended to include characters from different encoding like this: (Turkish characters)

```
title ~* '(^|[^\wğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ])samsung([^\wğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ]|$)
```

Here is a sample case where you may need the above extension. 

For example; in a Latin5 encoded database you have a value of 'İsamsung'. İ is the capital of i in Turkish. 
In this case the `title ~* '(\msamsung\M)'` does not work.
This criteria returns the İsamsung value. Because in Latin5 encoding, postgre thinks İ is out of alpanumeric range and the value is something similiar to :samsung.

Answer (score 2):

The following solutions are tested in PostgreSQL 9.6.

You may use the [`\y` **word boundary**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) and a grouping construct with alternation operator separating all possible alternatives:

```
where title ~* '\y(?:Samsung|phone)\y'
```

Or, case insensitively:

```
where title ~* '\y(?:Samsung|phone)\y'
```

See the [PostgreSQL demo](https://rextester.com/NCD74438).

Note that `\y` is not the right approach when the first or last char are not word chars. E.g. you want to search for `#samsung` or `phone#`. Then, **consider using unambiguous word boundaries**:

```
where title ~* '(?<!\w)(?:#samsung|phone#)(?!\w)'
```

Here, the `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is a non-alnum and no `_` char immediately to the left of the current position, and the `(?!\w)` is a negative lookahead fails the match if there is a non-alnum and no `_` char immediately to the right of the current position. Equivalent for testing if there is a match in `where` clause is:

```
where title ~* '(\W|^)(?:#samsung|phone#)(\W|$)'
```

See [another PostgreSQL demo online](https://rextester.com/JXJF56021):

```
CREATE TABLE mmytable
    (title character varying)
;

INSERT INTO mmytable
    (title)
VALUES
    ('#Samsung Co.'),
    ('They have a phone#'),
    ('Uncle Sam phoned him')
;

select * from mmytable where title ~* '(?<!\w)(?:#samsung|phone#)(?!\w)';
```

[image]

Also, consider **whitespace boundaries when you need to match only in between whitespace characters or start/end of string**:

```
where title ~* '(?<!\S)(?:#samsung|phone#)(?!\S)'
where title ~* '(\s|^)(?:#samsung|phone#)(\s|$)'
```

Or, in case you do not know if there can be a special char at the start or end of the string:

```sql
where title ~* '(?!\Y\w)(?:#samsung|phone#)(?<!\w\Y)'
```

where `(?!\Y\w)` and `(?<!\w\Y)` are *adaptive dynamic word boundaries*.