# SQL query to find exact words in any order

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have a postgres table `Article` which has three columns - `title`, `description`, `categories`. All the three columns contain plain text.

I have 2 search words - say `word1`, `word2`

I want to find the records where title+description+categories contains all the exact search words, in any order.

- need exact case-insensitive matches.
  Ex. man shouldn't match against woman.
- The search words can appear in any order Ex. If we search for "pollution global warming" - it should match against "... global abc warming adds to toxic mix of pollution..."

Need help in implementing a procedure(if not possible by query) where we can pass in the list of search words and it should return the list of records.

Any pointer will be a great help.

On a side note, I intend to consume this in django. If this requirement can be better achieved using django ORM, that should also suffice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521687/how-to-search-if-whole-word-exists-in-a-string-in-postgres may help you further.

Comment: [I downvoted because of "no research"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) Please do some research first, let people know what you tried and what did not work as you expected. See also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from (select lower(title || description || categories) as txt from t)
where txt like lower('%word1%') and txt like lower('%word2%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well considering that you don't want them in a specific order, you can match syntax by concatenating the two columns into a new column and then checking the condition for both of them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT LOWER(CONCAT(col1, ' ', col2)) AS conc_col from table)
WHERE conc_col LIKE LOWER('%word1%') AND conc_col LIKE LOWER('%word2%')
```

Notice that using AND will only return the string if both the words are present.